# If i use redirect_to i'll get Redirected too much on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My goal is to redirect user to `index path` if true else show `new path`.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_condition, only: [:index, :new]

  def check_condition
     if true
        redirect_to posts_path
     else
        redirect_to new_post_path
     end
  end 

  def index
     @posts = Post.find()
  end

  def new
     @new_post = Post.new(title: "test")
  end
end
```

I keep getting error redirected too much on the browser when I go to index path or new path

Comment: Your code is behaving exactly the way you've written it to behave. Before `index` or `new`, `check_condition` will always redirect to `index`. Upon redirect to `index`, before `index` is called, `check_condition` will redirect to `index`. Upon redirect to `index`, before `index` is called, `check_condition` will redirect to `index`. Upon redirect to `index`, before `index` is called, `check_condition` will redirect to `index`. Upon redirect to `index`, before `index` is called, `check_condition` will redirect to `index`.

Comment: You are running your `before_action :check_condition` before every action, even if you are already. for example, on the `index`. I cannot suggest a fix because it is unclear to me what you actually try to achieve. There are only these two methods, why do you need to redirect at all?

Comment: @spickermann it is very simple, if condition is true then go to index else go to new. How would I achieve that? If there are other ways to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you redirect to `post_path` every time when the if-condition is true no matter if you are already on the `post_path`.

You only need to redirect unless you are already on the path to the expected method. That can be done by checking the current [`action_name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-action_name):

```
def check_condition
  if true
    redirect_to posts_path    unless action_name == 'index'
  else
    redirect_to new_post_path unless action_name == 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: `method_name` is what exactly? sorry im new to ruby. I'm not sure what are you referring to

Comment: Sorry, I meant `action_name`, the method that I have linked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks man, now i know why it keeps on redirecting. I need to add `unless`

Answer (score 0):

You're running to an infinite loop of redirects.

You're adding `check_condition` as `before_action`. This means, every time you redirect to `index` or `new` pages, `check_condition` will run again without reaching `index` or `new` methods and redirecting again instead, and so on.

My suggestion is to write the condition checker in the `view` or in a `helper` method (to determine the path of the link in the first place), not in the `controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to return after redirect.

```
def check_condition
  if true
    redirect_to posts_path && return
  else
    redirect_to new_post_path && return
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but, what's the condition to check?  If the user is logged in?  I think your issue is probably too many redirect_to's.  Try:

```
def check_condition
     path = condition ? posts_path : new_post_path
     redirect_to path
end
```

Comment: How does this change the behavior? You just use a ternary operator instead of the if-else-block.

Comment: You're only using one redirect_to.  Perhaps both of your conditionals are hitting at some point...

Comment: How can both branches of a if-else-block being hit at the same time? That's ridiculous. If it was because the method was called twice that it would happen in your code too.